# Windows Error Code 0xc0000225 After Dual Booting Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

After finally being able to install and get Ubuntu to dual boot, I went back to Windows to get some files to transfer and I got the error code above. When installing Ubuntu I chose the something else option and created the partitions myself. How do i get windows to start working again?

Comment: this is windows 8

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need your Windows Install DVD/USB.

Pop that into your laptop and follow the prompts until you get an option to `Repair your Computer`. Click that, and follow the prompts again until you get to `Startup Repair`. Run that and the system will automagically try to fix any problems Windows may have.

Note that this might break GRUB2, thus not letting you into Ubuntu. To fix this, use an Ubuntu Live CD and run this command in an elevated terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Replace /dev/sda with whatever your Drive Identifier is. You can find this by using `lsblk` and looking for the drive with the most partitions on it.

Note: You may need to change your BIOS boot order to boot from the USB drive first.

This method does ***not*** cause data loss unless your system is seriously borked.

Comment: will i lose my windows8 data in this process or things which i have installed on ubuntu

Comment: i have a pendrive which is bootable of windows 8 will this help

Comment: @Abhijeet Edited answer for you.

Comment: i am very new to this..so kinda freak out what to do..thank u for ur answer..

Comment: @Abhijeet No problem. We were all noobs once.

Comment: not showing the option of startup repair..i choosed automatic repair bt it said couldnt repair ur pc

Comment: @Abhijeet http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on - Follow through step 2, part 1.